# NAT SMTP to a specific public IP on a Mikrotik

Tags: routing, nat, mikrotik

We had some peeps who supplied us a Mikrotik with our fibre connection, but have since moved the contract to another provider, and they don't want to help me configure the device. I desperately need a hand, I am out of my depth.

We have some public IPs 
154.117.185.242 - all normal traffic, surfing, guest wifi on this one
154.117.185.243 - our web server :80 is on this one 192.168.10.157 :80
154.117.185.244
154.117.185.245 - another web server :80 on this one 192.168.10.9 :80
154.117.185.246

For some reason 154.117.185.243 has been majorly blaklisted, I think someone had a virus. So I want to move outgoing SMTP (port 25) from 154.117.185.242 to 154.117.185.244 so that people can reliably recieve their transactional mail.

I tried to create this rule: srcnat src.add: 192.168.10.157 protocol tcp port 25 -> action src-nat to address 154.117.185.244 port 25  (I wish I could attach a screen grab)

But that did nothing.

To be honest, I don't even know where to begin creating this rule. I really need help.

I assume that response communication from the net will also have to have a rule to go back to 192.168.10.157:25 - but if that's neccessary I think for that I can pretty much copy one of the webserver rules and change port numbers. It's the rule for the outgoing stuff that I am really stumped with.

Thanks

Steve

**Edit - added export:**

```
# dec/20/2016 21:15:40 by RouterOS 6.30.4
# software id = UUL8-1EL2
#
/ip firewall filter
add action=drop chain=forward src-address=192.168.10.54
/ip firewall nat
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat dst-address=154.117.185.243 dst-port=80 protocol=tcp \
    to-addresses=192.168.10.157 to-ports=80
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat dst-address=154.117.185.243 dst-port=81 protocol=tcp \
    to-addresses=192.168.10.241 to-ports=81
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat dst-address=154.117.185.243 dst-port=82 protocol=tcp \
    to-addresses=192.168.10.242 to-ports=82
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat dst-address=154.117.185.245 dst-port=21-80 protocol=tcp \
    to-addresses=192.168.10.9 to-ports=21-80
add action=src-nat chain=srcnat protocol=tcp src-address=192.168.10.157 src-port=25 \
    to-addresses=154.117.185.245 to-ports=25
```

and the whole config:

```
# dec/22/2016 12:53:00 by RouterOS 6.30.4
# software id = UUL8-1EL2
#
/interface ethernet
set [ find default-name=ether1 ] comment="Bitco Fibre"
set [ find default-name=ether2 ] comment=Internal
set [ find default-name=ether3 ] comment=unused
set [ find default-name=ether5 ] comment="Guests Wifi"
set [ find default-name=ether6 ] comment=unused
/ip neighbor discovery
set ether1 comment="Bitco Fibre"
set ether2 comment=Internal
set ether3 comment=unused
set ether5 comment="Guests Wifi"
set ether6 comment=unused
/interface wireless security-profiles
set [ find default=yes ] supplicant-identity=MikroTik
/ip pool
add name=dhcp_pool1 ranges=192.168.22.100-192.168.22.254
/ip dhcp-server
add address-pool=dhcp_pool1 disabled=no interface=ether5 lease-time=1d10m \
    name=dhcp1
/snmp community
set [ find default=yes ] addresses=154.66.208.0/24
/ip address
add address=154.117.185.243/22 interface=ether1 network=154.117.184.0
add address=192.168.22.2/24 interface=ether5 network=192.168.22.0
add address=192.168.10.1/24 interface=ether2 network=192.168.10.0
add address=154.117.185.245/22 interface=ether1 network=154.117.184.0
add address=154.117.185.242/22 interface=ether1 network=154.117.184.0
add address=154.117.185.244/22 interface=ether1 network=154.117.184.0
/ip dhcp-server network
add address=192.168.22.0/24 dns-server=41.79.80.34,8.8.8.8 gateway=\
    192.168.22.2
/ip dns
set allow-remote-requests=yes servers=41.79.80.34,8.8.8.8
/ip firewall filter
add action=drop chain=forward disabled=yes src-address=192.168.10.109
add action=drop chain=forward disabled=yes src-address=192.168.10.28
add action=drop chain=forward src-address=192.168.10.54
add action=drop chain=forward disabled=yes src-address=192.168.22.116
add action=drop chain=forward comment="BLOCK SPAMMERS OR INFECTED USERS" \
    dst-port=25 protocol=tcp src-address-list=SPAMMER
add action=add-src-to-address-list address-list=SPAMMER address-list-timeout=\
    23h59m59s chain=forward comment=\
    "Detect and add-list SMTP virus or spammers" connection-limit=10,32 \
    dst-port=25 limit=10,5 protocol=tcp
/ip firewall mangle
add action=mark-routing chain=prerouting dst-port=25 new-routing-mark=\
    "Webserver SMTP" passthrough=no protocol=tcp src-address=192.168.10.157
/ip firewall nat
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment="webserver port 80" dst-address=\
    154.117.185.243 dst-port=80 protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.10.157 \
    to-ports=80
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment=CCTV dst-address=154.117.185.243 \
    dst-port=81 protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.10.241 to-ports=81
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment="unused CCTV" dst-address=\
    154.117.185.243 dst-port=82 protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.10.242 \
    to-ports=82
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment=xmpie dst-address=154.117.185.245 \
    dst-port=80 protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.10.9 to-ports=21-80
/ip route
add comment="send web SMTP through 244" distance=1 gateway=154.117.185.244 \
    routing-mark="Webserver SMTP" scope=255
add distance=1 gateway=154.117.185.217
/ip service
set telnet address=192.168.10.0/24
set ftp address=192.168.10.0/24 disabled=yes
set www address=192.168.10.0/24
set ssh address=192.168.10.0/24
set www-ssl address=192.168.10.0/24
set api address=192.168.10.0/24
set winbox address=192.168.10.0/24
set api-ssl address=192.168.10.0/24
/lcd
set time-interval=hour
/snmp
set enabled=yes
/system clock
set time-zone-name=Africa/Johannesburg
/system identity
set name=Bowens
/system routerboard settings
set protected-routerboot=disabled
/system script
add name=SPAMMERS owner=admin source=":log error \\\"----------Users detected \
    like \\\
    \n    SPAMMERS -------------\\\";\
    \n\\n:foreach i in \\[/ip firewall address-list find \\\
    \n    list=spammer\\] do={:set usser \\[/ip firewall address-list get \\\$\
    i \\\
    \n    address\\];\
    \n\\n:foreach j in=\\[/ip hotspot active find address=\\\$usser\\] \\\
    \n    do={:set ip \\[/ip hotspot active get \\\$j user\\];\
    \n\\n:log error \\\$ip;\
    \n\\n:log \\\
    \n    error \\\$usser} };\" policy=ftp,read,write,policy,test,winbox "
/tool graphing interface
add allow-address=192.168.10.0/24
/tool romon port
add
```

Comment: Add output of `/ip route export ` too

Answer (score 1):

If you already have mailserver inside, then there must be rules for that ip.  [Here](http://www.abuseat.org/lookup.cgi?ip=154.117.185.243) it shows that you have virus. Can you post router config ? `/ip firewall export file=fwexport.txt`

Changing IP wouldn't solve your problem. You must find infected computer.

**Edit**

You must setup packet marking and route SMTP traffic with specific marking to specific gateway. See [here](http://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?t=113968) and [here](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Per-Traffic_Load_Balancing). You must mark only traffic from web server. At this time i do not have spare router to test that. But hope You get idea. Also block SMTP traffic in guest wifi. [How to autodetect infected or spammer users and temporary block the SMTP output](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/How_to_autodetect_infected_or_spammer_users_and_temporary_block_the_SMTP_output)

`/ip firewall filter add action=drop chain=forward disabled=yes dst-port=25 in-interface=wlan1 log=yes protocol=tcp`

This rule will block all smtp traffic at 25 port from `wlan1` interface. When you correct rule, remove `disabled=yes` or enable it in GUI.

Comment: I can clean the infection (if it wasn't a guest on wifi) - I also want to block port 25 on 154.117.185.243 so that it remains clean. But first and foremost, I want my transactional mail from the web server 192.168.10.157 to be routed tough 154.117.185.244 so that it's nice and clean and separate from anything that might happen on 154.117.185.243 in future.

Comment: Added the export to the original question.

Comment: First you should stop smtp forward on guest wifi.

Comment: Sure, we can do that too. - so the guest wifi goes into it's own interface and is on a different subnet 192.168.22.

Comment: So, I added 
`/ip firewall mangle
add action=mark-routing chain=prerouting dst-port=25 new-routing-mark=\
    "Webserver SMTP" passthrough=no protocol=tcp src-address=\
    192.168.10.157`
And after some tweaking I got it working, the counter is counting traffic.
Now I am struggling with my "routing" rule.
`/ip route
add comment="send web SMTP through 244" disabled=yes distance=1 gateway=154.117.185.244 \
    routing-mark="Webserver SMTP" scope=255`
154.117.185.244 isn't the gateway is it? it's just the IP on that interface (ether1) that I want to use?

Comment: You have disabled that rule. What shows `/ip route export`?

Comment: I was still struggling with it, it was giving me trouble. It seemed to be stopping the mail, but now the mail is flowing even tho it is enabled.  `# dec/21/2016 11:43:22 by RouterOS 6.30.4
# software id = UUL8-1EL2
#
/ip route
add comment="send web SMTP through 244" distance=1 gateway=154.117.185.244 \
    routing-mark="Webserver SMTP" scope=255
add distance=1 gateway=154.117.185.217`

Comment: please post full router config, run `/export file=router.cfg` and then share that config.

Comment: If I do that, how do I get the file? - I'll edit it into the original question.

Comment: if you use winbox, then there is section `files`

Comment: See this thread http://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?t=37898